# Get the url parameters in php

Tags: php, url, get, webmethod

I have a url :

```
http://localhost:17080/SMSService/Getsms.php?to=100001&body=6260575535299&from=09350000008
```

‏ and I want to get the value of "to" , "body" , "from" .
how can I do this in php?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try the below..

```
<?php
   echo $_GET['to'];  
   echo $_GET['body'];  
   echo $_GET['from'];  
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but maybe OP wants just to parse an url. It could be something like this then:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$url = "http://localhost:17080/SMSService/Getsms.aspx?to=100001&body=6260575535299&from=09350000008";
$url_parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($url_parts['query'], $path_parts);

echo($path_parts['to']."\n");
echo($path_parts['body']."\n");
echo($path_parts['from']."\n");
?>
```

and output is:

```
100001
6260575535299
09350000008
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$_GET` superglobal:

```
if (array_key_exists('body', $_GET))
  echo $_GET['body'];
```

But this is *really* simple stuff. The [beginners tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php) in the Getting Started section on PHP.net already covers superglobals (although they start with $_SERVER rather than $_GET). If you desire to learn PHP quickly, it will pay to read a couple of those before asking questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

It is really simple.

```
<?php
$to = $_GET['to'];
$from = $_GET['from'];
......// and so on...
?>
```

For this to work, you need to store it in a php file.
Read more about this : http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php