# passing values from one php page to another

Tags: php

What I have been trying to do is this.
I created two files student_log.php and stu_det.php.Now I want to pass the student's roll no from student_log.php to stu_det .php
And I used this code:

```
<a href="stu_det.php? PID=<? php echo $ rno;>">details </a>
```

How do I retrieve this value in stu_det.php?

Comment: Try $_GET and [read more here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: It is better to remove space from substring `php? PID=`

Comment: <a href="stu_det.php?PID=<?php echo $rno;>">details</a>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the url parameters in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125659/get-the-url-parameters-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

First of all remove the extra space from your link, (seems like you have a few of them) .

```
<a href="stu_det.php?PID=<?php echo $rno;?>">
                    ^
```

Then in your `stu_det.php` you can simply fetch the value with

```
$value=$_GET["PID"];
```

That's the very basic way to get query string values. However you should add a check whether the value exists before you try to fetch it. That is like

```
if(isset($_GET["PID"]))
{
  $value=$_GET["PID"];
}
else
{
  echo "No PID value was received";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look after the spaces in query string

```
<a href="stu_det.php?PID=<?php echo $rno; ?>">details </a>
```